# How to combine N number of lines in a file into 1 line?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file which is formatted in below format:

```
create_terminal \
        -name {abc} \
        -port {abc} \
        -layer metal1 \
        -bbox {{2 0.000} {3 0.204}}
```

I want the output file to look like below:

```
create_terminal         -name {abc}         -port {abc}         -layer metal1         -bbox {{2 0.000} {3 0.204}}
```

Is there a quick sed or awk command to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\\\n/,"")}1' file
create_terminal         -name {abc}         -port {abc}         -layer metal1         -bbox {{2 0.000} {3 0.204}}
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk '{rec=rec $0 RS} END{gsub(/\\\n/,"",rec); printf "%s",rec}' file
create_terminal         -name {abc}         -port {abc}         -layer metal1         -bbox {{2 0.000} {3 0.204}}
```

or:

```
$ awk 'sub(/\\$/,""){rec=rec $0; next} {print rec $0; rec=""}' file
create_terminal         -name {abc}         -port {abc}         -layer metal1         -bbox {{2 0.000} {3 0.204}}
```

The above assumes you just want to remove all backslashes-followed-by-newlines. If you want something else then edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do it as:

```
awk  '!/\\\s*$/{f=1} {sub(/\\\s*$/,""); a=a""$0 } f{print a; a=""; f=0}' filename
```

Explanation:

```
awk  '
    !/\\\s*$/{f=1}        # set f=1 is line does not end with \ followed by whitespace(s)
    {sub(/\\\s*$/,""); a=a""$0 }    # substitutes the \ from the end of line with "" (nothing) and concatenates a with the current modified line.
    f{print a; a=""; f=0}        # prints a and reset the value of a and f. Runs only if f=1 is set
' filename
```

For input:

```
create_terminal \
    -name {abc} \
    -port {abc} \
    -layer metal1 \
    -bbox {{2 0.000} {3 0.204}}
temp_123 \
    -sdg
```

Output:

```
create_terminal         -name {abc}         -port {abc}         -layer metal1         -bbox {{2 0.000} {3 0.204}}
temp_123    -sdg
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try tr instead then pipe the output to sed, like this (assuming the file name is textf.txt):

```
cat testf.txt |tr '\n' ' ' |sed 's#\\# #g'
```

*NOTE:This works on OS X with BSD sed

Comment: That's a UUOC and will replace every individual backslash char or newline char with a space instead of stripping all backslash-followed-by-newline pairs and it will leave the output without a terminating newline. The whole thing could be written as just `tr '\\\n' ' ' < testf.txt` but that'd just be more concise and efficient, it'd still have those functional issues.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/\\$/{$!N;ba};s/\\\n//g' file
```